# nicedit formatting not being passed via jquery $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nicedit

I have a nicedit textarea.
When I click a button to send the data to a jquery $.get function, it doesnt send the formatting and just adds a tab space to the front of the data.

heres the form

```
<form id="myFrm">
 <input type="hidden" id="page_ref" name="page_ref"  value="<? echo $page_ref; ?>"/>
 <input type="hidden" id="template_ref" name="template_ref" value="<? echo $template_ref; ?>"/>
 <input type="hidden" id="box_id" name="box_id"/>
 <textarea name="edit_content" id="edit_content"></textarea>
 <div class="button">Save</div>
</form>
```

the textarea #edit_content is innitiated as a nicedit and filled with data from db here

```
 function get_edit_content(box_id,page_ref,template_ref)
   {
$(document).ready(function() {

  if(area1) {       
    area1.removeInstance('edit_content');
    area1 = null;
    document.getElementById("edit_content").value="";        
    }
    $.get("get_content.php", { box_id: box_id, page_ref: page_ref, template_ref:template_ref } )
  .done(function(data) {         
      document.getElementById("edit_content").value=data;          
      document.getElementById("page_ref").value=page_ref;
      document.getElementById("template_ref").value=template_ref;           
      document.getElementById("box_id").value = box_id;                  
      area1 = new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance("edit_content",{hasPanel : true});              
      });  
    });
   }
```

when I click on the 'Save' button I call this function

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('.button').click(function() {
     var edit_content = $('#myFrm').find('.nicEdit-main').text();       
     var box_id = $('#myFrm').find("#box_id").val();
     var page_ref = $('#myFrm').find("#page_ref").val();
     var template_ref = $('#myFrm').find("#template_ref").val();
     $.post("update_textarea.php",
      {
       box_id:box_id, page_ref:page_ref, template_ref:template_ref, edit_content:edit_content
      },
     function(data,status){                 
       alert(data);
       UpdateElementOfParent(box_id, page_ref, template_ref)            
       edit_box('hide')
     });
   });
  });
```

the 'alert(data)' returns the content of the textarea, but with no formatting and a tab space at the beginning of the content

any clues?

Comment: What do you mean by "formatting" ? How do you manage your server-side code ?

Comment: nicedit allows you to add formatting such as font size bold align etc to the text within the textarea. When I then pass that to the save function, all the formatting has been removed(or not added). I alert the 'var edit_content = $('#myFrm').find('.nicEdit-main').text();' and it returns the original text witha tab space at the beginning but no formatting. I know its not the serverside code as the formatting has been stripped(or not added) to the posted variable 'edit_content' because when alerted it doesnt have the formatting on it

Comment: "data" is the response object of your server-side code.
what if you do an alert of your edit_content var before uploading ?

Comment: yes I have tried that and i get the same response. the formatting is stripped (or the values passed to edit_content var are not updated) before the server side code is initiated.

Comment: Hummm I'm not sure but of how is niceedit working but it may come from your $.text() call.
Have you tried to replace it by $.html() ?
I mean, var edit_content = $('#myFrm').find('.nicEdit-main').html();
Because $.text() give you the plain text of your HTML element, but not a HTML content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you try using $.html() instead of $.text() ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.button').click(function() {
        var edit_content = $('#myFrm').find('.nicEdit-main').html();
        // console.log(edit_content);
        alert(edit_content);
        [...]
    });
});
```